# FLV Player to allow scrubbing forward?

Tags: flash, video, flv

Hey everyone.  Just wondering what everyone's thoughts are on playing FLV video on a website.  I'm currently using JW player and it works great.  The only problem is people can't scrub forward past what is cached.

For instance... i want to click on the video and immediately click half way through it to start playing in the middle of the video.  Can this be done with JW player, or do you suggest another FLV player?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called streaming.

Normally, you would need a RTMP server such as [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) or the open-source counterpart [Red5](http://osflash.org/red5).

There is a way to fake streaming using HTTP though. You could install a module on your webserver such as [Apache](http://tperspective.blogspot.com/2009/02/apache-flv-streaming-done-right.html) or [Lighttpd](http://blog.lighttpd.net/articles/2006/03/09/flv-streaming-with-lighttpd) that will allow you to jump forward when you click in your media player.

For your media player, JW Player, you can check how to enable the streaming via [RTMP](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player5Formats#RTMPStreaming) or [HTTP](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player5Formats#HTTPStreaming).

Comment: I would call it *'seeking'*.  'Streaming' is more broadly used than that.

Comment: True, seeking would be from the client point of view (and better describe what the OP was looking for) versus streaming that would be more from the server point of view IMO. But I prefer to give the term 'streaming' here as a Google search for 'flash streaming' or 'jwplayer streaming' will give more interesting results than the 'seeking' counterpart.